# Why does this code work on Windows but not on Mac?

Tags: python

It runs in command prompt, but when I try to run this on terminal (on a Mac), it stops working. The error is at line 21: `mystring = (f"{paragraphs[paragraph].getText()}")`, I get a syntax error.

```
import requests
import bs4
import csv
import os

os.chdir('filelocation')
counter = 0

text_file = open("file.txt","r")
lines = text_file.read().split(',')

mywebsite = input("please enter a website\n")

res = requests.get(mywebsite)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

paragraphs = soup.select('p')    

for paragraph in range(len(paragraphs)):
    if counter == 0:
        mystring = (f"{paragraphs[paragraph].getText()}")
        counter += 1
    else:
        mystring = mystring + (f"{paragraphs[paragraph].getText()}")

for line in lines:
    if line in mystring:
        print(line)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: 1) What's the error text? 2) On mac, are you using a version of Python which supports f-strings?

Comment: Are python versions on both systems the same?

Comment: sounds like the windows python version on windows is 3.6 or greater and 3.5 or less on mac. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: To check the version, you can run the following python script on both machines: `import sys; print(sys.version)`